# Equivalent of MySQL's \G in Oracle's SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

In Oracle's SQL*Plus, the results of a SELECT are displayed in a tabular manner. Is there a way to display a row in a key-value manner (like MySQL's [`\G` option](http://slaptijack.com/software/enabling-vertical-g-output-in-the-mysql-client/))?

The database I am working on (the schema is not defined by me) has a bunch of columns named e.g. `YN_ENABLED` (YN = yes no) which are `CHAR(1)`. So when I do a query I get a result like

```
ID_MYTABLE   Y Y Y
------------ - - -
3445         Y N Y
```

So it's not really clear which columns have which values (without having the schema open in another window).

Comment: This OTN thread http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=923884 discusses that.

Comment: Thanks! I tried Googling, but alas "equivalent to \G" isn't too Googleable.. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not built in to SQL PLus, but Tom Kyte has provided a procedure called [print_table](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1035431863958) that does this.  You would run it like this:

```
SQL> exec print_table ('select * from mytable where id_mytable=123');

And see results like:

ID_MYTABLE      : 123
YN_ENABLED      : Y
YN_SOMETHING    : N
...
```

Comment: Did Oracle implement it since 2010? I would like to use it inside SQL Developer to export cleaner results...

Answer (score 4):

I know your question is about SQL*PLus, but you might be interested to know that Oracle's SQL Developer can do this.  The feature can be used by right clicking on the Query Results and selecting "Single Record View...".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a trick that may do in a pinch if you don't want to (or cannot) install a new procedure on your server:

1. Select the row (or rows) of interest in the Oracle SQL Developer
   query results window.
2. Use `shift-control-c` in Oracle SQL Developer to copy the rows and
   headers to the clipboard.
3. Paste into your favorite spreadsheet
   (e.g., MS Excel).  Now you have records in rows.
4. Copy the rows that you just pasted into the spreadsheet
5. Use the "Paste Special - Transpose" feature of your spreadsheet program to paste the values into a new spreadsheet.  Now your records should be in columns.

Answer (score 2):

Coming in late, but I found this

```
SQL> select * from xmltable('ROWSET/ROW/*' passing xmltype(cursor(select * from emp where rownum = 1
)) columns name varchar2(30) path 'node-name(.)', value varchar2(30) path '.');
```

Found [here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/925884)

Comment: Works great for me. Top.